# Python array reference variables elsewhere

Tags: python, arrays, variables

Struggling to find an answer as I'm not sure on the exact wording I need so apologies.

Part of my script creates an array of values but I'm trying to reference these elsewhere to save speed. I have

```
def frame1():
  data = array.array('B' [1,2,3,4,5])
```

However I need to input 512 values into 720 frames and don't want to do this manually.
I want to be able to make a variable thats

```
hour = 1,3,5
minute = 2,4,6
```

and combine them in a frame to have

```
data = array.array('B' [hour + minute + minute])
```

to result in

```
data = array.array('B' [1,3,5,2,4,6,2,4,6])
```

Hopefully that makes sense!!

Comment: well, isn't that just `[1, 2, 3] + [2, 4, 6] * 2`? Btw your syntax for the function call isn't correct, missing a comma between the args

Comment: Apologies, perils of re-typing before coffee has kicked in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `hour` and `minute` are already lists, and so `hour + minute` is as well. You don't need to do anything special to make the new combined list from the sum; the sum *is* the combined list.

```
data = array.array('B', hour + minute + minute)
```

Strictly speaking, this is inefficient, as repeatedly concatenating two lists results in O(n^2) behavior. A better solution for more, longer lists would be to use `itertools.chain`.

```
from itertools import chain

data = array.array('B', chain(hour, minute, minute))
```

Depending on your actual code, this may or may not make an appreciable difference in the running time.

Comment: I knew it would be simple! It would appear I was getting bogged down in too many layers of brackets. Thank you!